# difference between variable and reference assignment

Tags: c++, reference

This has bothered me, I have just gotten back into c++ lately, and am well aware of references. Why does it seem there is no difference between b and c below. In other words, intuitively I would think c not being a ref variable would take a copy. It got me thinking when considering the problem of returning a reference to a local variable.

```
int a = 10;
int& func()
{
   return a;
}

int &b = func();  
int c = func(); // shouldn't this make a copy into c but c acts like a reference.
```

Comment: `c` is a copy. Modifying `c` will not change `a`: https://godbolt.org/z/GT4EneEbj. Can you specify what is your question here?

Comment: "_but c acts like a reference_": That's simply not true. How did you come to this conclusion? Maybe show some code demonstrating the behavior that made you come to this conclusion.

Comment: "_It got me thinking when considering the problem of returning a reference to a local variable._": Returning a local variable by-reference doesn't work, even if you immediately store a copy in a variable. The local variable is destroyed _before_ the function returns. Accessing the return value of a function returning a reference to a local variable _always_ causes undefined behavior.

Comment: The code doesn't use the variable `c` after initializing it, so the assertion in the comment that `c` "acts like a reference" cannot be based on this code. Post code that shows `c` acting like a reference. Hint: it can't be done.

Comment: *In other words, intuitively I would think `c` not being a ref variable would take a copy.*  Your intuition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I would think `c` not being a ref variable would take a copy.

`c` is indeed a copy of `a`. Note that `int c = func();` is *[copy **initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)* while `int &b = func();` is *[reference **initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)*.

This means that if you make changes to `c` they will not be reflected on `a`. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ywUla-TUE)

```
int a = 10;
int& func()
{
   return a;
}

int &b = func();  //reference initialization
int c = func();   //copy initialization
int main()
{
    c = 20;
    std::cout << a<< " "<< b <<" "<< c <<std::endl; // 10 10 20
    return 0;
}
```

Note also the emphasis on "initialization" instead of "assignment". These terms have different meaning in C++ unlike other languages(python for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, makes sense now. This question started from "why can't I return a local variable reference to a variable if its a copy?" Well, I realized because its too late at that point - the stack is gone. I was thinking the copy could be made before the stack went away - wrong!
You can return to a reference but when you use it, segfault.
Return to a variable and, segfault immediately since it tries to copy.

```
int& func()   // compile warning
{
   int a = 10;
   return a;
}

int &b = func();  // ok, but segfault if try to use b.
int c = func(); // segfault immediately
```